# ITask и TParallel.For, время выполнения

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Пытаюсь выполнить 10(например) задач за один раз, но по итогу выполнения кода ниже, получаю вместо 1-ой секунды, 2-3 секунды.
Что я делаю не так и как это исправить, возможно есть другой способ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tasks: array of ITask;
  value: integer;
  i: integer;

  Start, Stop: integer;
  Elapsed: integer;
begin
  Start := GetTickCount; // засекли начало выполнения операции

  Setlength(tasks, 10);
  value := 0;

  TParallel.For(0, 10 - 1,
    procedure(i: integer)
    begin
      tasks[i] := TTask.Create(
        procedure()
        begin
          Sleep(1000);
          TInterlocked.Add(value, 1000);
        end);
      tasks[i].Start;
    end);

  TTask.WaitForAll(tasks);

  Stop := GetTickCount; // засекли окончание выполнения операции
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr((Stop - Start) / 1000) + #10 + 'Всего: ' + value.ToString);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы 10 задач выполнялись одновременно, нужно иметь как минимум 10 свободных ядер на процессоре. Другого способа нет.

Если у вас процессор, например, 4 ядра, то за первую секунду выполняться только 4 задачи, а остальные будут ждать освобождения ресурсов (свободного ядра). За вторую секунду еще 4, и за третью оставшиеся 2.

Операционная система пытается грамотно распределить ресурсы процессора и, когда в потоке выполнения вызывается `Sleep`, ОС запускает на этом ядре другие потоки. Пока поток спит, на этом ядре могут выполняться другие потоки, возможно даже и ваши следующие задачи. По этому иногда получается 2 секунды, а не 3.

Answer (score 0):

Потоки создаются на усмотрение системы. Я немного изменил ваш пример и стал запоминать время старта и окончания каждого потока:

```
Var    
  tasks: array of ITask;
  strs: Array[0..9] of String;

Function MakeTask(i: Integer): TProc;
begin
Result := procedure()
  begin
  strs[i] := 'start: ' + TimeToStr(Now) + 
             ' id: ' + IntToStr(TThread.Current.ThreadID);
  Sleep(20000);
  strs[i] := strs[i] + ' ... ' + 
                       'end:   ' + TimeToStr(Now);
  end;
end;
```

Паузу выбрал побольше (20сек), чтобы лучше понять поведение системы. Далее, пытаемся запустить десять потоков параллельно. Это можно делать и через Parallel.For, но можно и напрямую запустить:

```
for i := 0 to 9 do tasks[i] := TTask.Run(MakeTask(i));
TTask.WaitForAll(tasks);
```

В результате, получаем в strs следующее:

```
start: 8:03:04 id: 3760 ... end:   8:03:24
start: 8:03:04 id: 2720 ... end:   8:03:24
start: 8:03:05 id: 4620 ... end:   8:03:25
start: 8:03:06 id: 1924 ... end:   8:03:26
start: 8:03:07 id: 3184 ... end:   8:03:27
start: 8:03:08 id: 3372 ... end:   8:03:28
start: 8:03:09 id: 4448 ... end:   8:03:29
start: 8:03:10 id: 2016 ... end:   8:03:30
start: 8:03:11 id: 4328 ... end:   8:03:31
start: 8:03:12 id: 4456 ... end:   8:03:32
```

Общее время выполнения от 8:03:04 до 8:03:32, то есть 28сек. Из них 20сек - sleep последнего потока, а ещё 8сек понадобилось на запуск потоков, потому что они запускаются по 2 в секунду. Очевидно, что они в какой то момент работали параллельно - все 10 штук, но запускались зачем-то с большим интервалом 0.5сек.

Запуск через Parallel.For приводит к такому же результату, только нарушается порядок потоков.

На маленьких sleep'ах потоки также запускаются по два в секунду, и система обходится всего тремя потоками вместо десяти, как это было при долгой задержке.

```
start: 8:07:22 id: 3304 ... end:   8:07:23
start: 8:07:22 id: 2856 ... end:   8:07:23
start: 8:07:23 id: 3304 ... end:   8:07:24
start: 8:07:23 id: 2856 ... end:   8:07:24
start: 8:07:23 id: 2212 ... end:   8:07:24
start: 8:07:24 id: 3304 ... end:   8:07:25
start: 8:07:24 id: 2856 ... end:   8:07:25
start: 8:07:24 id: 2212 ... end:   8:07:25
start: 8:07:25 id: 3304 ... end:   8:07:26
start: 8:07:25 id: 2856 ... end:   8:07:26
```